# Application does not run in background mode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, info.plist

I have set "Application does not run in background mode" property key to YES and when I hit the home button it only puts the application into background mode when I click home button twice the app is still running in background and when I relaunch the app the application will enter foreground method is called . I have a setting bundle that creates tabs for UITabBarcontroller and I want the app to quit as it need to run the setup method to work out which tabs to show . I tried to use application will enter foreground to remove view controllers from the tabbar controller by reading the settings bundle and it works but the application will enter foreground method is no good as I can not re-add the view controllers I removed if the settings are changed back again so my only option is to quit the app and the application did launch with options method alloc and init all view controller b  reading the setting bundle first . Is there any other way to quit the app

Comment: I've look at other question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637111/application-still-running-in-background-xcode-4-2-ios-5 but the answer the answer tell him to add the same key

Comment: Ive just started to use xcode 4.2 on os x 10.7.3 with SDK 5 can I still use no background key in info.plist

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The fact that your app's icon is listed once you double press the Home button is *not indicative that it is running*.  At best, it indicates which apps the user used last.
2. *"Running in the background"* and *"loaded into memory, ready to resume"* are not the same thing.  It's a bit similar to how you can shutdown a computer (it's not processing anything), and if put a computer to 'sleep', it's still not processing… but the state of the computer is kept.

I would invite you to read the **suspended** and **background** states : [App States and Multitasking](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html).

Comment: Ive read the document it was the fact the application was entering the background and not quitting I found the issue I was using Test Flight SDK as soon as I turned off Test Flight the application started behaving as normal and not going into background mode so if any one else has this issue and is using Test Flight SDK that will prevent your application from behaving as expected  if setting  "Application does not run in background mode" in info plist

Comment: I wanted it to quit I know the icon in the background list dose not mean the app is running in background but It was suspended and that's not what is ment to happen when setting info.plist key  "Application does not run in background mode"